# How to reproducably cause / provoke a ReflectionTypeLoadException?

Tags: .net, exception, reflection, types

Sadly, references to this exception are usually of an exotic nature and can happen when you e.g. enumerate Types via `Assembly.GetTypes()` - case in point, it is happening on one of our deployments but the same set of assemblies work fine on the Integration Server.

In order to harden against this type of error I would like to be able to provoke such an exception to see if my exception handling code works as expected.

Hence any pointers would be useful, e.g. just knowing what kind of things cause this exception.

<strike>**EDIT**
My attempt so far:</strike>

- Define a type in assembly A which uses an attribute of assembly B
- Have some code iterate over all types in the assembly where said
  attribute is specified.
- I build the attribute only when DEBUG flag is true
- I then copy the release build of that dependency into the relevant folder

But I only manage to get a `TypeLoadException` with a pretty clear error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following causes this exception:

You have assembly A which defines the following class:

```
public class AC
{
    public BC GetBC() { /* ... */ }
}
```

You have assembly B which defines the class `BC`.
Now, when you load Assembly A and get the members of class `AC`, for example using `assembly.GetTypes().SelectMany(t => t.GetMembers()).ToList();`, the framework tries to resolve `BC`. It even knows that it is in assembly `B`. However, if the framework resolves an assembly `B` that doesn't contain `BC`, a `TypeLoadException` will be thrown. This can happen, if assembly `B` is not up-to-date, because you forgot it in your deployment.

**UPDATE:**
To actually get a `ReflectionTypeLoadException`, the scenario is very similar. However, you don't need to have a method in `AC` that returns `BC` but you need to derive `AC` from `BC`:

```
public class AC : BC
{
}
```

Using the `LoaderExceptions` property, you can retrieve the exceptions that lead to this `ReflectionTypeLoadException`. In my case, this is a `TypeLoadException` stating exactly what type it couldn't load.

Comment: I tried this with 2 projects: One iterates over its own types of which one has a public method exposing a type of  the second project. That type only gets compiled with debug flag. I then copy the release build dependency into the folder containing the executing assembly and I get no exception...

Comment: You are right. You need to enumerate the members, too. But this will only give you a `TypeLoadException`, not a `ReflectionTypeLoadException`... Strange.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach if you wish to test how your code handles the exception is to use mocking in your testing. With mocking you can mock out the assembly loading sub-system and concentrate on testing how you handle the resulting exception - much more straight-forward.

Using mocking you would use an `IAssemblyService` instead of calling `GetTypes` on `Assembly` directly. In your mock you can throw the required exception. It is more usual to use a mocking framework such as FakeItEasy, but the following uses a hand-rolled mock for demonstration.

In your test you would substitute your real assembly service with `MockAssemblyService`.

```
internal class MyTypeThatLoadsStuff
{
    public MyTypeThatLoadsStuff(IAssemblyService assemblyService)
    {
        //Do stuff with assemblyService
    }
}

internal interface IAssemblyService
{
    IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes();
}

internal class AssemblyService : IAssemblyService
{
    private readonly Assembly _assembly;

    public AssemblyService(Assembly assembly)
    {
        _assembly = assembly;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes()
    {
        return _assembly.GetTypes();
    }
}

internal class MockAssemblyService : IAssemblyService
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes()
    {
        throw new ReflectionTypeLoadException();
    }
}
```

And with a mocking framework such as FakeItEasy:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    IAssemblyService service = A.Fake<IAssemblyService>();

    ReflectionTypeLoadException ex = new ReflectionTypeLoadException(
        new[] { typeof(SprocketTests) }, new[] { new Exception() });

    A.CallTo(() => service.GetTypes()).Throws(ex);

    MyTypeThatLoadsStuff loader = new MyTypeThatLoadsStuff(service);

    //test...
}
```