# Get types in assembly: ReflectionTypeLoad Exception

Tags: reflection, c#-4.0, assembly.reflectiononly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reproducably cause / provoke a ReflectionTypeLoadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162289/how-to-reproducably-cause-provoke-a-reflectiontypeloadexception)

I wanted to get all types in a loaded assembly.code snippet is as follows

```
Assembly assemblyObj = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\abc\abc.dll");
            IList<Type> types = assemblyObj.GetTypes();
```

when i run im getting ReflectionTypeLoadException.What is the mistake in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in my answer to the question linked as duplicate, the problem most likely is, that "abc.dll" contains a class that derives from a class in a referenced assembly and that referenced assembly doesn't contain that base class, because it has the wrong version.