# GetExportedTypes() on an assembly throws NotSupportedException

Tags: windows-phone-7, reflection

I'm having some serious troubles getting a Windows Phone 7.5 class library to load into the WP Unit Test Framework. It internally calls GetExportedTypes() on my assembly which throws a ReflectionTypeLoadException that doesn't contain any details. Its message is "ReflectionTypeLoadException" and its LoaderExceptions is null ("Could not evaluate expression"). The assembly is not using any 3rd party assemblies. If I create a separate WP7 app and do the same thing, I get the same results. I'm a very experienced Reflection user, but the lack of any detailed errors has brought my research to a complete halt. Just for completeness, it's the Windows Phone version of Fluent Assertions.

Comment: "Could not evaluate expression" and `null` are not the same. You could try catching the exception in code and access the `LoaderExceptions` there.

Comment: I've tried, but I get the "Could not evaluate expression" when I probe the LoaderExceptions.

Comment: Don't "probe". Assign it to a variable and maybe even convert it to a string if you still can't see its value in the debugger...

Comment: Very strange. What about `InnerException`?

Comment: null as well. In my entire carreer as a .NET developer I've never seen such a weird exception before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it! [@GeertvanHorrik](http://twitter.com/GeertvanHorrik) pointed me at a [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20111230171548/http://blog.catenalogic.com/post/2011/08/27/Windows-Phone-7-and-MissingMethodException.aspx) he recently wrote. I was using an covariant interface (using the *out* parameter) which the runtime (!) doesn't support. Why the compiler does not protect me from that is a big mystery (and a huge disappointment) to me

Comment: FYI, blog post link now returns a 404.

Answer (score 1):

What about the `Types` array on the exception? Does it contain values? If so, does it also contain `null`s? If so, you can find out which classes failed to load: You know all classes in the assembly and you know which classes loaded correctly. Those that are missing are the classes that couldn't be loaded. Maybe this info gives some clues.

This answer is based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.reflectiontypeloadexception.aspx), especially these bits:

From the Remarks of the `LoaderExceptions` property:

> The LoaderExceptions property retrieves an array of type Exception that is parallel to the Types array. This array will contain null values whenever reflection cannot load a class.

And from the documentation of the `Types` property:

> An array of type Type containing the classes that were defined in the module and loaded. This array can contain some null values.

Comment: Nope. It is <null> (and no, not empty)

Comment: Wow. Now you need to start from the beginning: (1) Create a test application that loads your assembly via reflection and verify it failes as described (2) Remove classes from this assembly until loading doesn't fail anymore (3) You now got the offending class and can hopefully find the problem.

Comment: But what kind of construct could cause this? Knowning that should help me to figure out the root cause of this all.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162289/how-to-reproducably-cause-provoke-a-reflectiontypeloadexception/7162415#7162415) for one possible reason for this exception. Why all properties of the exception are null is something I have no answer for.

Comment: After many hours of trial-and-error, I've tracked down the problem to a nested class in my project. See http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/81156#1605504. Whenever I avoid a call to its Use() method, the problem disappears. What's so special about this class that WP7 chokes on it?

Comment: @DennisDoomen: I don't see anything special. Are all the types used in this class in the same assembly?

Comment: Yes. The main assembly doesn't have any dependencies on other 3rd party code.